# Segmentation Fault in C++ implementation of Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, kruskals-algorithm

I have written this code which implements the Kruskal's algorithm for Minimum Spanning Tree, which yields segmentation fault when I submit it to an online judge. I think I have narrowed the cause of segmentation fault to the part where I sort the edges. Still, I can't find the exact reason why this code fails.

```
struct DisjointSet{
    private:
        struct Node{
            int size;
            int repr;
            Node(int rep){
                size = 1;
                repr = rep;
            }
        };
        vector<Node> nodes;
    public:
        int makeSet(){
            nodes.push_back(Node(nodes.size()));
            return nodes.size() - 1;
        }
        int findRepresentative(int ind){
            if(nodes[nodes[ind].repr].size == -1){
                nodes[ind].repr = findRepresentative(nodes[ind].repr);
            }
            return nodes[ind].repr;
        }
        void unionSets(int ind1, int ind2){
            int rep1 = findRepresentative(ind1), rep2 = findRepresentative(ind2);
            if(rep1 != rep2){
                if(nodes[rep1].size < nodes[rep2].size){
                    int t = rep1;
                    rep1 = rep2;
                    rep2 = t;
                }
                nodes[rep1].size += nodes[rep2].size;
                nodes[rep2].size = -1;
                nodes[rep2].repr = rep1;
            }
        }
};

bool compare(const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &p1, const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &p2){
    return (p1.second <= p2.second);
}

int spanningTree(int V, int E, vector<vector<int>> &graph) {
    vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int>> edges;
    for(int i = 0;i < V;i ++){
        for(int j = 0;j < V;j ++){
            if(i <= j){
                if(graph[i][j] != INT_MAX){
                    edges.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(i, j), graph[i][j]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sort(edges.begin(), edges.end(), compare);
    DisjointSet d;
    for(int i = 0;i < V;i ++){
        d.makeSet();
    }
    int weight = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < edges.size();i ++){
        int u = edges[i].first.first, v = edges[i].first.second;
        if(d.findRepresentative(u) != d.findRepresentative(v)){
            d.unionSets(u, v);
            weight += edges[i].second;
        }
    }
    return weight;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, and locate *exactly* where in your code it happen? It will also allow you to check the values of all involved variables at the time of the crash, to make sure they are all valid (i.e. no out-of-bounds indexes etc.)

Comment: Your compare function does not implement strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the test on which the code runs was provided by an online judge, and so I can't tell for sure how the code fails. However, I used an alternate Prim's algorithm implementation and used it to locate the cause of the bug. Its seems to arrive from the line where I sort the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compare function:

```
bool compare(const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &p1, const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &p2){
    return (p1.second <= p2.second);
}
```

does not provide a strict-weak ordering, since comparing 2 elements `e1` and `e2` with the same `.second` will return true for *both* `e1 < e2` *and* `e2 < e1`, which is not allowed. Using this `compare` function in sort invokes undefined behavior, potentially causing a segfault.

You need to do something like:

```
bool compare(const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &p1, const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &p2){
    return p1.second < p2.second;
}
```